# VAE autoencoder training fit_generator doesn't seems reduced the loss

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried to use the fit_generator function. It's weird that when I use fit_generator, the loss seems just slowly going down by a little. Like I already trained about 5 days my loss just decrease from 129 to 119. But I have search how long should the model training and it said on the internet like only 8 hours. I do think it's my problem but i don't know what is the problem so I wish somebody could help me! And my data was only using 100 images only.

Below is my training code

```
vae_model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss = total_loss, metrics = [r_loss, kl_loss],experimental_run_tf_function=False)
N_EPOCHS = 3000 
zz = '/weights.h5'
vae_model.load_weights(zz)
checkpoint_vae = ModelCheckpoint(zz, save_weights_only = True, verbose=1)

vae_model.fit_generator(data_flow, 
            shuffle=False, 
            epochs = N_EPOCHS, 
            initial_epoch = 0, 
            steps_per_epoch=tr_num / BATCH_SIZE,
            callbacks=[checkpoint_vae])
```

```
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0005
LOSS_FACTOR = 10000

def r_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis = [1,2,3])

def kl_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    kl_loss =  -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_var - K.square(mean_mu) - K.exp(log_var), axis = 1)
    return kl_loss

def total_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return LOSS_FACTOR*r_loss(y_true, y_pred) + kl_loss(y_true, y_pred)
  
adam_optimizer = Adam(lr = LEARNING_RATE, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)
```

Comment: Could you share the weights.h5 file.